# Error: First argument must be a data frame or shared data

Tags: r, plotly, shinydashboard

I want to create dynamic plots based selectorInput in shinydashboard, but when I want to create plot I get error:

> First argument, `data`, must be a data frame or shared data.

Here is part of my code is Server part when I try to subset data and use them as plotly input:

```
data_sub = reactive({
data_sub_temp = df[df$market == input$market_selector,]
return(data_sub_temp)
  })


  output$market_plot <- renderPlotly({
  plot_ly(
  data = data_sub,
  x = ~ created,
  y = ~ pax,
  group_by = ~ type,
  color = ~ type,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "lines+markers",
  hoverinfo = 'text',
  text = ~ paste('Year:', created,
                 '</br> </br> Clients: ', pax)
  )  
  })
```

Dataset is loaded and pre-processed before UI&Server code part. When I use dataset subsetted before UI&Server part this code works, I am unable to maket it work when data_sub part is added. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: The problem might be that the plot is not reactive to the input, so it doesn't get the data when it's supposed to. Have you considered using an `eventHandler` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the `dataframe` part is `reactive`, but not the plot. You can try using an `eventHandler` instead. In this case, you need to add an `actionButton` in the ui (possibly in the `sidebarPanel`) and add the `eventHandler` in the server, without the `reactive` part. 
Code below.

**ui**

```
 actionButton(
      inputId = "submit_loc",
      label = "Submit")
```

**server**

```
observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input[["submit_loc"]],
    handlerExpr = {

data_sub <- df[df$market == input$market_selector,]

output$market_plot <- renderPlotly({
  plot_ly(
  data = data_sub,
  x = ~ created,
  y = ~ pax,
  group_by = ~ type,
  color = ~ type,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "lines+markers",
  hoverinfo = 'text',
  text = ~ paste('Year:', created,
                 '</br> </br> Clients: ', pax)
  )  
  })

})
```

Try and let me know whether this works.

Answer (score 0):

Reactive is used to limit what gets re-run during a reaction. The `reactive({})` expression creates reactions similar to `input$...` expressions.

I.e in your example pulling `data_sub` out of the `renderPlotly()` expression would prevent renderPlotly from running when `df$market` or `input$market_selector` change unless you tell shiny that `data_sub` must be reactive as you have done above. There is little point in isolating `data_sub` from your `renderPlotly()` expression unless other `input$...` expressions were causing `renderPlotly()` to redraw.  See [Reactive Tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/) for a better understanding.

If you wish to keep `data_sub` reactive you need to call it using the bracket notation in your plot. I.e `data = data_sub()`

It may also be useful to get a grip on assignment operators in R as you are using the `=` operator incorrectly. Your code will still run however it is better to use the `<-` operator for `data_sub`. See [Difference between assignment operators in R](https://renkun.me/2014/01/28/difference-between-assignment-operators-in-r/).

The final code should look something like:

**Server**

```
data_sub <- reactive({df[df$market == input$market_selector,]})

output$market_plot <- renderPlotly({
  plot_ly(
  data = data_sub(),
  x = ~ created,
  y = ~ pax,
  group_by = ~ type,
  color = ~ type,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "lines+markers",
  hoverinfo = 'text',
  text = ~ paste('Year:', created,
                 '</br> </br> Clients: ', pax)
  )  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `data = data_sub()` instead of `data = data_sub`

```
output$market_plot <- renderPlotly({
  plot_ly(
  data = data_sub(),
  x = ~ created,
  y = ~ pax,
  group_by = ~ type,
  color = ~ type,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "lines+markers",
  hoverinfo = 'text',
  text = ~ paste('Year:', created,
                 '</br> </br> Clients: ', pax)
  )  
  })
```